# Bootstrap unwanted .active class with scrollSpy

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a `navbar` using Bootstrap and trying to use `data-spy="scroll"`. But it keeps on applying an `active` class to the rightmost `navbar` item (which is contact in this case) which is undesired, and I need to have activated `nav` items as I scroll down to the specific section.
When I click the items in the `navbar`, the jump to the specific section is fine.

Part of the HTML code:

```
<body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="60">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#myPage">My Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center full-screen">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="services" class="container-fluid text-center full-screen">Services</div>
  <div id="about" class="container-fluid text-center full-screen">about</div>
  <div id="contact" class="container-fluid text-center full-screen">Contact</div>
</body>
```

and the CSS code:

```
.full-screen {
  height: 100%;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #32db61;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  padding: 254px 25px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  line-height: 25px !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}
.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand{
  color: #fff !important;
}
.navbar-nav li a:hover, .navbar-nav li.active a {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

Comment: Must be pure CSS solution or we can use JS ? :)

Comment: for the moment pure CSS should work :)

Comment: The whole purpose of scrollspy is to apply the active class. If all three sections are visible scrollspy simply applies the active class to the last one, in this case contact.

Comment: But the first I have a jumbotron and then sections starts with their `id s`. So basically i assume no active class should be there when the site is loaded, as the height of the sections and the jumbotron is read from CSS and only jumbotron is visible without any scroll. @reinder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved once I added `<!DOCTYPE html>` code at the beginning of my html file.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can use jQuery this will do the job:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   $('.navbar-right li').removeClass('active');
  //in case you want to remove all actives after loading
  //$('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```